# SSH Permission denied (publickey) fails on Ubuntu but succeeds on MacOS

Tags: ssh

I have two machines, a MacOS and an Ubuntu. I have been working sucessfully on the MacOS, i.e. I can use my public key to connect via SSH to a server. However, when trying to use the same private & public key on a new Ubuntu machine in order to connect to the server it fails.

One to thing to note, is with MacOS it is suing SSH v1 and Ubuntu SSH v2.

**1. MacOS**

```
/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa
/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
/home/richardm/.ssh/config
/home/richardm/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Config

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ServerAliveInterval 240
User = richard
ForwardAgent yes
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Terminal output:

$ ssh -A -J richard@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX dev-myco-node01 -vvv

```
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

**2. Ubuntu**

```
/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa
/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
/home/richardm/.ssh/config
/home/richardm/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Config

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
#  UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ServerAliveInterval 240
User = richard
ForwardAgent yes
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Terminal output:

$ ssh -A -J richard@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX richard@dev-myco-node01 -vvv

```
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
richard@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey).
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote
```

Comment: Generally, for two different clients, you should use two different pairs of private/public keys.  i.e., you shouldn't copy the Mac one over to the Ubuntu system.  Instead, you should generate a new pair and copy the public key over to the server so that the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` has two public keys.   By doing this, you might solve your problem since the Ubuntu system will be using a key the is correct for its version of `ssh`.

Comment: Hi @Ray, thank you for your feedback.  I agree that it would strictly be the correct way to do it, however I was told by our server admin/devops person that I must copy over the keys from the mac to ubuntu machine, because it saves him from having to add the pub key to the authorized_keys. I unfortunately don't have access to the server to add the key myself.

Comment: Good grief... Wow. If this is in a professional setting, can you report that to whoever is in charge of IT security? In the meantime, it looks like the keys haven't been copied correctly. How are you expected to copy them if you cannot ssh? Or can you still ssh using a password? If so, have you tried just adding the key normally with `ssh-copy-id`? Also, what are the permissions of all these files and dirs? What is the output of `ls -ld ~/.ssh ~/ssh/id* config known_hosts`  on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I copied the ~/.ssh from the Mac to the Ubuntu laptop, hoping that it would use the same keys and provide the same access. I did set the permissions to:  chmod 700 ~/.ssh, chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa (I have also tried setting all to 777).

Comment: I haven't tried: ssh-copy-id.  I do not have authority to copy keys to the servers, that's the domain of our devops person who said I should just copy my keys from the Mac to the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I don't see a problem with using the same private key on two clients that are both under your control. And you shouldn't need to do anything else if the corresponding **public** key is already on the jump host. However I'm confused why you appear to be using both ProxyJump (via the `-J` option) and agent forwarding - afaik the latter shouldn't be necessary if you are using the former?

Comment: If I just try connect to the proxy, it still gets the error.  I now try: ssh -A richard@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX -vvv to try connect just to the proxy, but this fails too. debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:CKEVXXXXXXXXFrkI sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation

Comment: ... you're still requesting agent forwarding (`-A`)

Comment: sorry, tried, ssh richard@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX. Same error again

Comment: I guess it's still getting the agent forwarding stuff from your .ssh/config file - this really isn't my area of expertise, but I think it should be possible to use a much simpler jump configuration similar to this U&L answer [ssh config identities specified by IdentityFile are not forwarded by ForwardAgent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444394/65304)